# Ruby on Rails - Create polymorphic comment through partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism

I'm currently trying to implement polymorphic comments within my app, but I'm running into problems with converting my partial form.

I was following this tutorial, [step-by-step-guide-to-polymorphic-associations-in-rails](http://karimbutt.github.io/blog/2015/01/03/step-by-step-guide-to-polymorphic-associations-in-rails/), but it didn't go over this section.

Mainly, I have an Image that is commentable, and a partial at the bottom to allow users to comment on the Image.

However, when submitting the form, it can't find the `@commentable` object as `params[:id]` and `params[:image_id]` are both nil.

I'm having problems understanding how I'm supposed to pass this information, as the partial knows this information, but the controller does not.

// images/show.html.erb

```
<div class="container comment-form" >
    <%= render 'comments/form', comment: @image.comments.build  %>
</div>
```

// comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :message, :hide_label => true, :placeholder => 'Add a comment' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Reply', :class=> 'btn btn-default pull-right' %>
<% end %>
```

// comments_controller.rb

```
def create       
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params) <<<<<

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to (comment_path @comment), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Error on `@comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)`

`undefined method`comments' for nil:NilClass`

I also noticed that there is no `id` in the request parameters.

Parameters:

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxx", "comment"=>{"message"=>"nice photo"}, "commit"=>"Reply"}`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a record to a form builder rails uses the [polymorphic route helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)* to lookup the url for the action attribute.

To route to a nested resource you need to pass the parent and child(ren) in an array:

```
bootstrap_form_for([@commentable, @comment])
# or
bootstrap_form_for([@comment.commentable, @comment])
```

This would give the path `/images/:image_id/comments` for a new record and `/images/:image_id/comments/:id` if it has been persisted.

Comment: * note that this has nothing to with polymorphic associations. In this case `polymorphic` means that they are smart and can figure out the route to whatever objects you toss at it.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, but used `commentable` instead of `@commentable` within my `form_for`. Also needed to ensure that the resources were nested so the route existed.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to build your comment twice.  Once in the show.html, with `comment: @image.comments.build` and then again in your create method with `@comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params) <<<<<`

The tutorial you linked to included the private method below.  If your goal is to create a comment that belongs to your Image object, the method below would look for a param with your `image_id`, and would return `Image.find(params[:image_id])`

```
def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

You could change your `show.html` to pass in your image_id as a hidden param with:

```
<div class="container comment-form" >
  <%= render 'comments/form', image_id: @image.id  %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. When I replace that with `image_id`, I run into the issue where my `form_for` fails due to the `comment` being nil. I tried with both `comment` and `@comment`, but both are nil.